# imagemapster: keep altimage turned on after mouseout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas

I'd like to keep my altImage turned on when I mouseout. i.e. Mouseover either of the "i"s  on this page: http://cjehost.com/qt/nipt/page10.php

and you'll see the altImage appear. I want the altImage to display onMouseout as well. Here is my code for this area:

```js
key: 'blue2',
  stroke: false,
  fill: true,
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fillOpacity: 1,
  strokeColor: 'ff3333',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  isMask: false,
  onMouseout: null,
  altImage: 'http://cjehost.com/qt/nipt/images/pan-page10-over-1300.png',
  altImageOpacity: 1,
  altImageFill: true
```

Comment: This is the entire script: jquery.imagemapster.js:

Comment: view-source:http://cjehost.com/qt/nipt/src/jquery.imagemapster.js

Comment: any ideas? Possible to create something like "altImage2" and adjust code so the altImage stays "on" onmouseout?